Story about siblings with magic dice
The main things I remember aren't much, but I hope can help someone figure out what the book was. I found it in middle school, so would assume it's a children's book, but YA children not 5yr old children book.
The main characters were two siblings. An older brother and a little sister. They are in like our world, not in some mystical fantasy world. I don't remember how or why, but they get magic dice.
When the little sister rolls the dice at one point early on, a satyr comes out of a painting. He becomes their companion and helps them. (Sorry if I got name wrong, but he had got horns and goat legs?)
In the end and climax I can't forget they rolled the dice again in a time of need (think the brother is the one who rolls it) and suddenly all the lion statues come to life to save/protect them. The biggest one having wings and they get to ride on its back which I found so awesome I still look at gargoyles fondly wondering "what if?".

In roughly which year did you read this?
